# Issue with returning values from invoking same function multiple times

Tags: c++, return, invoke

Ok, so I'm doing this homework assignment and my teacher's first language is not English and is not always the best at giving directions.  I'm trying to write a program that asks for a midterm score and a final exam score and then adds those two values to display a total score.

My problem is that it doesn't seem to return the entered scores or store them in their respective variables in order to be added together (aka it always displays zero as the total)

Here is my code:

```
// Lab11P2.cpp

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double getNcheckScore(double, double);

int main()
{
    double midterm = 0.0;
    double final = 0.0;
    double total =0.0;

    cout << "MIDTERM EXAM" << endl;
    midterm == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);

    cout << "FINAL EXAM" << endl;
    final == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);

    total = midterm + final;
    cout << "Total score: " << total << endl;   

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

    double getNcheckScore(double midterm, double final)
{
    double score = 0.0;
    cout << "Please enter your score: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (score < 0 || score > 100)
    {
          cout << "Score must be between 0 and 100.  Please enter again: ";
          cin >> score;
    } 
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> midterm == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);

Don't use ==, this is a comparison operator. Use = for assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `==` instead of `=` here:

```
midterm == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);
```

and here:

```
final == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);
```

So these are not assigning values to these variables at all. Which is a good reason to compile with warning turned on because you would have seen something like this:

```
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
 midterm == getNcheckScore(midterm, final);
```

which would have been a good clue. Also you are not doing anything with the two arguments to your function:

```
double getNcheckScore(double midterm, double final)
```

but if you plan to eventually pass back the data through these arguments they will need to be references, like so:

```
double getNcheckScore(double &midterm, double &final)
```